# Is image segmentation using neural networks always supervised?

Tags: image-segmentation, unsupervised-learning

Is there a crucial distinction between semantic and just normal image segmentation with neural networks? Is non-semantic segmentation some type of unsupervised pixel-clustering method?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look to [W-net](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.08506.pdf), you can see that you can do unsupervised segmentation with deep learning.